# Availability Check record in database

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do is empty the textbox if value is already exist in the database. But the problem is it also empty the textbox even though the value is not exist in the database.

On the first try and input value that not exist in database, the textbox is not got empty. But when I tried to input a database that exist the problem continuing even though the value is not exist. Why is that?

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#username").change(function() 
{ 
var username = $("#username").val();
var msgbox = $("#status");

if(username.length > 4)
{
$("#status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "ajax.php",  
    data: "username="+ username,  
    success: function(msg){  
   $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){ 
    if(msg == 'OK')
    { 

        $("#username").removeClass("red");
        $("#username").addClass("green");
        msgbox.html('<img src="available.png" align="absmiddle">');
    }  
    else  
    {  
         $("#username").removeClass("green");
         $("#username").addClass("red");
         $("#username").val('');
        msgbox.html(msg);
    }  

   });
   } 

  }); 

}
else
{
$("#username").addClass("red");
$("#status").html('<font color="#cc0000">Please nter atleast 5 letters</font>');
}
return false;
});

});
</SCRIPT>
```

Here's my Ajax

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $sql = mysql_query("select id from code where username='$username'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql))
    {
        echo '<STRONG>'.$username.'</STRONG> is already in use.';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'OK';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: try to debug your var "msg" is the correct value inside? e.g console.log(msg);

Comment: what is the response you got from ajax.php and mention your dataType ?

Comment: in console log it gets the message of Ok and already in use which is correct. The only problem is why it's got empty?